# Font-embedding: what is wrong here?

Tags: css, fonts, embedding

I'm still pretty new to html and css, so I might be overlooking things.
Been entertaining myself trying to create a little website and arrived at embedding a font to it.
It is working in firefox, yet in internet explore it isn't. I do not know about other browsers.
Here is a link to the site. Click the L to go to a second page:
http://librarchive.com/newcat.html.
Due to this there are also some positioning faults, as you can see.

So the font is not correctly working. What do I do?

Here is my css code, i have a .eot and .ttf file of the font:

```
@font-face{ 
font-family: libralust; 
src: url('Futura_Bk.eot'); /* For IE */ 
src: local('libralust'), url('Futura_Bk.ttf') format('truetype'); /* For non-IE */ 
}

body {
font-family: libralust, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
}
```

I've been searching, but am not experienced enough to understand it all.
Other commentary about site is appreciated too. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Where did you get the font from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this a an example of cross-site font embedding has suggested by [fontsquirel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'OpenSansLight';
    src: url('/skins/default/media/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/skins/default/media/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/skins/default/media/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/skins/default/media/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/skins/default/media/fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#OpenSansLight') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

}

Now you can figure out what's wrong ?

I'll point another hint : **local**

For a detailed explanation read this : [the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax)  and/or  [bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)

Comment: the local(as the rest of the code) was suggested by the ttf-> eot convertor, and as i didn't knew what it does, I just copied it over.
I guess it is a good idea to get the .woff and .svg versions too. Any converters you would suggest?

and the #iefix... what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support Font-Face and there are lots of font ext; like eot, svg, woff, ttf.

Try this since you only have eot and ttf:

```
@font-face{ 
    font-family: libralust;
    src: url('Futura_Bk.eot');
    src: url('Futura_Bk.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Futura_Bk.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal; /* thin? normal? bold? */
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: any suggestions for converters to .svg, .woff?

Comment: @Pépé Artist The only one I recommend is http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. Since we are helping you please vote up.

Comment: I would, but my reputation doesn't allow yet